# Dualboot not functioning properly (GRUB not launching?)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have Windows 10 installed on my computer, and I decided to dual-boot Ubuntu. I booted the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS installer from a 64-gigabyte SanDisk USB Flash Drive and proceeded through the steps of the installer. When I finished I rebooted my computer to find that **GRUB** isn't launching (I thought it would override the default boot manager), so I tried editing my BIOS boot order to find it but could not find it. So I booted into Windows to examine what had changed and found that a new partition was not created on my disk. I thought it was an error so I booted back into the Ubuntu installer and again proceeded through the steps until I landed upon this page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7szw.jpg (I cannot post images yet)

I selected this option, and when it finished, I booted back into Windows to find the partition had been created, but still no GRUB, I also tried again to edit the boot options and change the BIOS, but still could not find GRUB anywhere.

My computer boots from UEFI, so I can't use something like EasyBCD to configure the boot options.

I am not too skilled in this area, so I would please like some assistance.

Comment: What brand, model system? Some like Acer require "trust" setting in UEFI. Some like HP only let to change boot order in UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, turn off fastboot in windows, then open the windows command line and run "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi" without the quotes and reboot. You should then be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to work. It didn't work at first, but I just had to disable **Secure Boot** in my BIOS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to install grub manually.

You can do this by booting into a Live CD or USB, mounting the root partition of the system that contains the GRUB bootloader, and then running the `grub-install` command. Specify the root partition.

`grub-install /dev/sdaX`

And then update the GRUB configuration.

Run `update-grub`

Then reboot the PC.

If you can't boot into the live boot device, you have to look into how to do that first.